# How to duplicate a product that already has attributes and replace its name? - Odoo15

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I'm having problems trying to duplicate a product that already exists, what I wanted was to click on a button and it would run a function to duplicate the article that is being represented on the page with all the attributes of the old product.
If anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate it.

*My attempt:*

```
def action_create_custom_product(self):
    new_product = self.env['product.template'].copy(
        self.article_id.id, 
        default={
            'name': self.article_id.name,
            'list_price': self.production_price()
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `copy` on `self.article_id` recordset.

***Example:***

```py
self.article_id.copy(
    default={
        'name': self.article_id.name,
        'list_price': self.production_price()
    }
)
```